# Propagate omitted types in union type after a boolean check

Tags: typescript

In typescript, the following will type correctly:

```js
let v: number | null | undefined;

if(v === null || v === undefined) return;

// v is typed as `number`
const v2 = v + 2;
```

However let's suppose we created a helper function for the `null` and `undefined` check. Typescript will complain about this:

```js
let v: number | null | undefined;

const isNull = (v: number | null | undefined) => v === null || v === undefined;

if(isNull(v)) return;

// v is typed as `number | null | undefined` 
const v2 = v + 2;
```

Is there any way to propagate up the equality check for `null` and `undefined` from the the helper function `isNull`?

I guess one could override it with `v!`, but seems hacky/dangerous since now the two are decoupled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the [type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=5&ssc=92&pln=4&pc=3#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABFApgZygCgJQG8BQiiANilIgG4BciYIAtgEYoBOiAPrSMcR4uABMUwGGBQCA3PkKIICDIhhoAct14BeRDKKZqXJqz50efQcNHjsNCorRcTnMyLEDE6gHyU36zcd7tOGx9NJwtJaSIYYEwlVR5dbGxEFjIQFjApGQB6LK8lZABPAAdxRABDOwADOgM2Tj9TMCFncUqtIjkwBQoAJjcvAGpEHqkAXyA) `v is null | undefined` to `isNull`.

```
const isNull = 
    (v: number | null | undefined): v is null | undefined => v === null || v === undefined;
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=5&ssc=92&pln=4&pc=3#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABFApgZygCgJQG8BQiiANilIgG4BciYIAtgEYoBOiAPrSMcR4uABMUwGGBQCA3PkKIICDIhhoAct14BeRDKKZqXJqz50efQcNHjsNCorRcTnMyLEDE6gHyU36zcd7tOGx9NJwtJaSIYYEwlVR5dbGxEFjIQFjApGQB6LK8lZABPAAdxRABDOwADOgM2Tj9TMCFncUqtIjkwBQoAJjcvAGpEHqkAXyA)

Comment: Sometimes the hardest thing about programming is figuring out what a certain abstraction is called. Thanks!